# Java - FlowPanel - Use a parent variable from a child

Tags: java

```
public class PageIndex extends FlowPanel {
    private PageHeader header;
    private PageCenter center;
    private PageFooter footer;
    public PageIndex() {
        this.header=new PageHeader();
        this.add(header);

        this.center=new PageCenter();
        this.add(center);

        this.footer=new PageFooter();
        this.add(footer);
   }
}

public class PageCenter extends FlowPanel {
    private PageMenu menu;
    private PageContent content;

    public PageCenter() {
       this.setStyle("center");

       this.menu=new PageMenu(content);
       this.add(menu);

       this.content=new PageContent();
       this.add(content);
   }
}

public class PageMenu extends FlowPanel {
    private PageContent content;
    private PageMenuLogin login;
    private PageMenuSearch search;
    private PageMenuOffers offers;
    private PageMenuStudents students;
    private PageMenuShopping shopping;
    private PageMenuEvents events;
    public PageMenu (PageContent content) {
        this.content=content;
        this.login=new PageMenuLogin();
        this.add(login);
        this.search=new PageMenuSearch();
        this.add(search);
        this.offers=new PageMenuOffers();
        this.add(offers);
        this.students=new PageMenuStudents();
        this.add(students);
        this.shopping=new PageMenuShopping();
        this.add(shopping);
        this.events=new PageMenuEvents();
        this.add(events);

        // IF I WRITE THIS I GET AN org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        this.content.daghine();
    }
}
```

I need to manage the content instance, but is not visible. Sorry, Im a bit rusty :)

Comment: You need to pass 'this' through to the constructor, as demonstrated in my code.

Comment: Ok. I thought there were another way :) I'll try to edit the code...if i have problem i'll let you know!

Comment: Well, there is, but it requires nested classes.

Comment: Uhm...watch the code above. I get an error. Why? Where im wrong? thank for your time man :)

Comment: oh it works! just i need to switch PageContent over PageMenu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you need to manage the variable? You're inside the object, that should allow you to do anything you need. If you need access to the parent object, do this:

```
public class PageIndex extends FlowPanel {
    protected final PageContent content;
    ...

    public PageIndex() {
        content = new PageContent(this);
        this.add(content);
        ...
    }

    public PageContent getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
}

public class PageContent extends FlowPanel {
    protected final PageIndex index;

    public PageContent(PageIndex index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public PageIndex getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public void exampleFunction() {
        createLabel().setLabel("HOLAAA").setStyle("content_title");
    }
}

public class PageMenuLogin extends FlowPanel {
    protected final PageIndex index;

    public PageContent(PageIndex index) {
        this.index = index;
        index.getContent().exampleFunction();
    }

    public PageIndex getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you need to access the PageHeader from outside the PageContent method, you can simply put the header variable on the PageContent class.

something like the following should get you started...

```
public class PageContent extends .... {
    private PageHeader header;
    public PageContent() {
       this.header = new PageHeader()
    }

    // add setHeader/getHeader methods here.

}
```

Comment: it doesnt work! i edited my topic with more details. How you can see i can't call that function...